# passwordless ssh login to same linux server

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I need a passwordless login using ssh to the same server.
I had done this before on the same server and it had worked.

```
cd ~
ssh-keygen -t dsa

cd ~/.ssh/
ssh-copy-id -i   id_dsa   <user@target-system>
```

I have used the steps shown above.

I am trying the same now and followed all the possible solutions but it's not working.

When I run ssh in `debug` mode , I get the following errors/warnings:

```
 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 No credentials cache found

 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 No credentials cache found

 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 No credentials cache found
```

Can someone help on this?

Now everytime I try to ssh, it prompts for the password.

Comment: This sounds like a question to post in either [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as it does not seem to have much to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. For some preliminaries: 1) check file permissions on `~/.ssh` directory and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file; 2) run ssh with '-v' so that you see what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Probably permission issue on `$HOME/.ssh` on target host.

To verify that check if something similar to

```
sshd[1235]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/someuser
```

appears in authlog (`/var/log/auth.log` in case of Debian/Ubuntu) of target host.

If so do the following on target host as user you're trying to logon to

```
chmod o-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Permissions are same as above.